# Take a sequence of elements from an array from i to j using C# and extension method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, arrays, extension-methods

I have an `Array<string>`. I have to take all elements from `i` to `j`. How can I make this using an extension method?

Comment: What do you mean "take"?  What kind of return value would you be expecting?  IEnumerable<String> perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetRange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int start, int end) {
  return enumerable.Skip(start).Take(end-start); 
}
```

Then you can do

```
Array<string> arr = GetSomeArray();
var res = arr.GetRange(i,j);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = myStringArray.Skip(i).Take(j-i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [ArraySegment<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx).

If you need this returned as an `IEnumerable<T>`, the options using Skip/Take already listed will work very well.